# What design principles are important for doing "more with less"?

Tags: interface-design, user-experience

What design principles can be used to achieve **simplicity** without diminishing the ability of the user to use an interface efficiently for **complex** tasks?

Specifically, I'm wondering which **[key design principles](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30262/what-are-the-key-principles-that-effective-designs-share)** I can use to achieve **more with less**. Principles that allow a designer to cover complex interface features with simplified, minimalist, design.

Comment: Big question! I'd suggest finding a copy of Universal Principles of Design and reading the sections titled **Flexibility-Usability Tradeoff**, **Layering**, **Progressive disclosure**, **Advance organiser**... then maybe browse the "see also"s

Comment: Key design principles that would help: Magic.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Magic? You mean to tell me you think that there are no such things as key principles by which we can establish good design practice?

Comment: In general, of course they are, and work well. But the image I had on my mind when reading the question was of a pretty complex system, and that interface that is really easy to use, but covering advanced control. I read it, and thought "Sounds like a dream! So use magic!" :) Could be my imagination was somehow exagerated, but still, I think you're asking for something like "the holy grail" of UI design. Which makes it an excellent question, btw.

Comment: My goal with this question was to get the community thinking about graphic design solutions in an objective way, taking the game out of the "designer's taste" field, and into the field of objective development, letting taste and designer creativity take hold of the design after balanced, proper thought has been put into the task. I find that many designers "just wing it", all of the time.

Comment: Which is OK! If it works, it works, but now, many of us feel that if asked a general design question, we must scoff, and claim that the question is wholly subjective, when in reality, very objective design principles can be applied to any situation in graphic design. If we think about design situations properly, and use objective thinking, describing the way specific design principles can be applied to achieve effective solutions, we can teach people to make better graphic design who don't know how to "wing it"

Comment: "I want something professional, but completely casual. Also, make sure it appeals to 4 year old girls and 60 year old men. Oh! And it has to work on both Google Chrome as well as my TI-80 graphing calculator!"

Comment: The problem isn't the question being to broad, it's that answerers are too unfocused. Try approaching the question from an objective, principle based position as requested by the question and supplied by my answer.

Comment: I don't generally agree with closing questions that have more than 2 answers. It would be a terrible shame to leave this as one. I did some editing to try and make it more focused based on some of the info from the answers, do you think there's anything else we can add? Also created meta post: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/945/what-do-do-with-on-hold-questions-that-have-positive-votes-and-multiple-answers

Comment: I urge you to read this: http://www.adaptivepath.com/ideas/in-defense-of-hard/

Comment: @Ryan the edited version of this does imply that question, but it wasn't my intention. Rather, I mean to ask about the principles involved with "doing more with less" - a minimal design for a complex application.

Comment: @user568458 Have a look at this version of the question with an improved scope and detail. Better?

Comment: @JonathanTodd I closed this for a duplicate.  I would hope to see you in chat like Bakabaka has mentioned in hopes we can discuss this and possibly find a way that we can improve your current question over the other.

Comment: @Gramps have a look at the edits that I have made, looking back at this question. I think now it might no longer be a duplicate.

Comment: @Bakabaka I've edited this question heavily. Have another look.

Comment: @Gramps In changing the question, I've attempted to retain it's original basis in order to ensure that all the good answers here continue to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having minimal buttons is the signature of a clean and simple interface. Find your top few interactions and give them buttons so they can be 1-click operations.

If those interactions have advanced features, give them a toggle/dropdown/submenu of some sort, ideally 2-click operations.

Anything you expect your users to rarely click can be deeper in the interaction. You don't want 100 operations as the level/submenu as it will become cluttered. Based on your overall complexity, stagger your levels to keep a balance of levels/submenus vs overcrowding each one.

Try and keep everything but the rarest of interactions within 3-clicks if possible. Your groupings of functions may help you decide where they should go. Always group similar actions and try and combine functionality when possible (ie: a toggle switch instead of both an on and off switch)

Take a look at a few sites and count the clicks to the tasks you typically do. A well designed site will take typical user interactions into account. Everything you'd typically interact with should be in an intuitive location without looking cluttered.

Comment: There are some things which are rarely done but when they are, they are done 1000 times (mass data entry etc). Consider this when burying functionality.

Comment: I think you could sum this up as 'prioritize tasks, and surface the common ones"

Comment: Another answer based on a common design principle. Perfect. +1 - Now if any one of these answers could just incorporate 3 of these principles into an answer, we'd have a solid, complete answer.

Comment: @JonathanTodd I think you're asking too much out of answers to these types of questions. Lots of GD questions are simply going to produce several subjective responses. It's your duty to pick one, not the duty of those taking the time to answer to write extensive summaries of all the subjective responses.

Answer (score 2):

To make your application easy to understand, use common elements and symbols that people are familiar with, rather than making them learn new symbols. Organize the system so that it walks the user through a process (e.g. step 1 should clearly navigate to step 2). Keep your navigation consistent (e.g. always keep your "save to draft" and "submit" buttons in the same order). If you have a dashboard or home screen, organize it well so that similar processes are grouped together.

The book, [Don't Make Me Think](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321344758), has great advice. Another good book is [Neuro Web Design: What Makes Them Click?](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321603605).

Comment: Very good example: Widely known or obvious icons. This is exactly the sort of answer I'm looking for. Maybe you could elaborate on a few other design aspects in order to provide a more complete answer?

Answer (score 1):

You ask how?

For many people there are many different ways. 
This is what I do:

Write down the functions of your application. 
Then start putting the functions into "categories", for example: 
functions: chat, add friends, ignore list, play video. I can put "chat", "add friends" and "ignore list" into the same category, because they are related.

After this you can create a wireframes, a simple block version of your app and you can put your categories in.  
Then just have fun with the graphic design.

For a complex application I would keep the graphic design open and simple. Maybe with the user of colors for each category, or simple icons. You need to make it look as if it is very easy.

I hope this answer helps you. 
As I've said earlier in this answer, everyone has his own way of making an overview of their project.

Good luck.

Comment: Please focus on specific, key principles of graphic design so the answer might have a solid, complete, objective foundation, rather than simply a helpful, suggestive one

Answer (score 1):

Focus on **meaning**.  Here are some thoughts:

To make something meaningful, you need to profile your target user: What does she know about this new task? Are there similar tasks (perhaps from other domains) that can acts as metaphors or illustration?

Simplicity should be the result of making things meaningful. Don't focus on simplicity. Simplicity can hide the real thing and make things harder to understand: less meaningful.

Be forgiving, and allow users freedom to play and do things in different ways. This is much more work to implement, but will make users happy because it gives control.

Keep a good eye on [locus of attention](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taouu/html/ch04s01.html). We humans are easily distracted and focus on one thing at a time. It's therefore making things meaningful if an interface takes this into account.

Read books, and learn about human nature, psychology, ergonomics, ... Interesting company is [IDEO](http://www.ideo.com).

It's a staccato answer, but I hope it sets you off. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to design an interface that clients don't have to spend more than a few minutes learning to use, but still offer advanced control of the the features that the application offers.

These, I would argue, are unrealistic requirements. At least, they are unrealistic until some user research is performed.

So that's where I'd start. The design principle I'd go with is [user-centered-design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-centered_design).

Upon researching the needs and habits of the users, however, we may very well come to the conclusion that the tasks simply are complex, and that trying to force them into a 'simple' UI may actually be a detriment to the user. To figure that out, I'd use [A/B testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing).

In summary, I'd leverage User Experience testing and research principles first and foremost.

Comment: Yet another important principle of graphic design well summarized and applied to the question. Could you incorporate a few of key principles that best relate to this in order to achieve a balanced, well rounded answer founded objectively?

Answer (score 0):

Key principles to achieve a good interface with complex content... I am here going to assume more of an *application* than a standard company website (what, where, who, when).

First; as indirectly mentioned in a comment above; make things as simple as possible but not one bit simpler. The article **[In defence of hard](http://www.adaptivepath.com/ideas/in-defense-of-hard/)** has some really good points in that department. Do not dumb down, if it is complex then do not force it to be simple. Complex is good. Complex is interesting. Done well.

As an analogy: creating something - anything for 10 year-olds does not mean to boil things down to the lowest common denominator. 10 year-olds are *used to* that there are a lot of stuff they do not know and have to work out. This also goes for adults. Spoonfeeding simplicity is dumbing down both the user and the creator. Important things gets lost.

- First, I would say: use elements that are *known* to users in
  general. To navigate *space* in some way, the principle elements of
  Google maps and/or Google Earth is pretty much universally
  understood. Plus, minus, zoom, move, overview etc .
- Also, the principles of computer games such as first-person adventure
  should also be pretty clear.
- To navigate time, there are timelines galore. And to combine
  time-space well can be very difficult but absolutely doable.

Using elements that most people are familiar with; there is no need to reinvent the wheel over and over. *Most* things have been done or attempted. Stand on the shoulders of giants, learn what complex interfaces fail and rethink the concept.

The art is to keep complexity, but not overwhelm the new user. Display the basics immediately, then increase options gently.

That, methinks, is the basic principles.

Comment: Oh, and I am going to toot my own horn; how to fail spectacularly with complex information: http://visualsquirrel.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/what-is-wrong-with-interactive-information/